# Visual Studio и Makefile

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Надо было тестово собрать один проект под VS для проверки совместимости кода, в общем все собирается, но выдает следующее:

```
warning C4530: Использован обработчик исключений C++, но семантика уничтожения объектов не включена. Задайте параметр /EHsc
```

проект собираться через `Makefile`
что это за беда такая? и собственно чего он по сути хочет? кроме как добавить ключ.

Comment: Если используются исключения, то проект должен быть собран с ключем `/EHsc`.

Comment: ... иначе объекты созданные в функциях вызываемых внутри блока `try` могут не быть корректно уничтожены. [Детали](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2axwkyt4.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, то есть для MSVS надо дописывать этим ключом `CFLAGS` обязательно. @Fat-Zer, оформите в виде ответа, отмечу как правильный.

Comment: гмм... не люблю я давать ответы на то, в чём я не разбираюсь и не могу проверить... если ни кто другой не оформит, то если не забуду, через пару дней напишу.

Comment: хорошо, ждем :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и говорит предупреждение, компилируется C++ код с обработчиками исключений, но ключ `/EH` не указан. Если верить [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2axwkyt4.aspx), то в данном случае объекты с автоматическим временем хранения, созданные в функциях вызываемых внутри блока `try` могут не уничтожиться корректно, о чём компилятор и сообщает.

Как описано в [справке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model), ключ `/EHsc` устанавливает режим обработки исключений:

- `s` указывает, что следует обрабатывать только исключения C++, но не *SE* (см. далее).
- `c` указывает, что функции объявленные как `extern C` не могут выкинуть исключения C++, в связи с этим компилятор вправе применить некоторую оптимизацию накладных расходов.
- Также возможно указание параметра `a` (вместо `sc`), при котором обычный блок `catch(...)` помимо обычных исключений C++ будет ловить и  *структурированные исключения* (*structured exception*), которые обычно отлавливаются внутри непереносимых блоков `__try`/`__except`.